# Displaying currency with converted price for the NON in-app products (Physical Products)

Tags: ios, objective-c, currency, price

I am working on a application which lets the users to purchase the physical things. I need to show users the converted price to the country they belong.

**Point to Note** :
 1. I will know the country of the user from google places api at the time of signup.
 2. I am using stripe payments where the user will save their card details.

**Example** :
My application is selling a WATER BOTTLE costing $10
So for the users who has signed up and chose their country as :

USA the price will be shown as $10

India the price will be shown as 670 INR

X country will show their price in their currency.

Comment: IMO unless you have the ability to bill the user's card in local currency you should just display the amount you will bill in the currency you will bill (e.g. US$) since the actual exchange rate that they will be charged (plus any applicable foreign transaction fees) will be determined by the card issuer

Comment: @Paulw11 : Yes that i what i am doing it right now showing the $ price to all the customers but in the application the prices set for the products are also in different currencies. Eg: A customer from India post a product for 100 Rupees then a another customer from USA will find this product and we need to show then 100 rupees into Dollor

Comment: Well, there are probably services on the Internet that can give *an exchange rate*, but this won't be *the exchange rate* that the user will be charged.  Recommending services, however, is off-topic for SO.

Comment: It would be best for your own service to provide the price by country. Otherwise, you can use some service for the exchange rate and add a disclaimer that what they actually will be charged might be slightly different.

Comment: @Cabhara :
Can you suggest reliable service which provide the currency conversion ?

Comment: Till now i found this :

http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=USDINR=X&f=sl1d1t1ba&e=.csv

USD to INR